# Mat-Dialog & Popover z-Index

Tags: angular, angular-material, z-index, ngx-bootstrap

I manually repositioned the Mat-Dialog from

> @angular/material

and tried to force the Popover Plugin (I tried ngx-popper and ngx-bootstrap) content to show in foreground of the dialog but i couldn't figure out how to solve it.

Comment: `z-index` in css not solving it?, if so then use `position:absolute;` with `z-index`

Comment: Sadly not. I tried every z-index configuration and it seems like the mat-dialog is able to force itself into the foreground...

Comment: The Popover is already using position:  absolute; z-index : 2000 And the Modal Dialog is using position: relative; z-index: 500;